# Are all continous functions topologically conjugate to some piecewise linear function?

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems

We've had a number of interesting questions on topological conjugacy on this site. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2175520/proving-that-the-tent-map-is-topologically-conjugate-to-the-quadratic-map) shows how to prove the tent map is topologically conjugate to the quadratic map, and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188756/use-the-definition-of-topologically-conjugate-to-prove-that-fx-4x3-3x-is?rq=1) shows that another piecewise linear function can be shown to be topologically conjugate to $F(x) = 4x^3 - 3x$. This got me wondering, given any continuous function, can I find some piecewise linear function that is topologically conjugate to it?

Comment: Hint: Think of a self-map $[0,1]\to [0,1]$ whose fixed-point set is the Cantor set.

Comment: This is an intriguing example, but I worry that I'm not getting the hint. It seems to me that a piecewise linear function could be designed to do this.  Though in this case, it would need infinitely many 'pieces' to get the job done?

Comment: Then what is your definition of a piecewise-linear function?

Comment: Thinking about this a little more I see your point. If I let my piecewise-linear function have infinitely many segments the question is trivial since I can approximate any function arbitrarily closely. Otherwise, I can't account for maps with infinitely many fixed points. Do counterexamples with finitely many fixed points also exist?

Comment: Of course: Take a function $f: [0,1]\to [0,1]$ such that $f^{-1}(0)$ is the Cantor set. Such a function can be chosen to have only one fixed point.

Comment: Ah yes! That makes sense. I'll have to think more about this. Thanks for the counterexamples!